# Problem while using ''clear'' command

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation

normally When i run `clear` my terminal would clear.

but when i enter  `clear` it give me output :

```
The program 'clear' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ncurses-bin
```

and when i type : `sudo apt-get install ncurses-bin`

i gives  me this output :

```
ncurses-bin is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I think it's source list issue.

SO how can i solve this !

Comment: What happen if you run `/usr/bin/clear`?

Comment: Do this `apt-cache policy ncurses-bin`. Is it in `Installed` state? If yes, try to reinstall `apt-get install --reinstall ncurses-bin`. Posted an answer as well, accept it if its what you need then.

Comment: done @AizuddinZali   install --reinstall command solved my issues :)

Comment: A shorter way to clear your terminal is `Ctrl+L`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the `clear` command was missing.

To check if `ncurses-bin` installation state: `apt-cache policy ncurses-bin`.

In this case reinstall might cure the problem: `apt-get install --reinstall ncurses-bin`